# Using urlize on untrusted text in django

Tags: django, markdown

I want to implement some basic markdown in my django app. The goal is to take user input and format it with linebreaks and url recognition.

I know I can do this in the template with:

```
{{ text|urlize|linebreaks }}
```

Is there a way to do this in a view with untrusted user input? Sort of like this:

```
from django.utils.html import urlize 

def foo(request):
    text = urlize("<script>console.log('break')</script> www.bar.com")
    return render(request, 'index.html' {'text':text})
```

i.e. have it render a link as safe, but not the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is likely no (given your sample text)

The docs for [`urlize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) state the following:

> If urlize is applied to text that already contains HTML markup, things won’t work as expected. Apply this filter only to plain text.

If you look at the source or `urlize`, though, it is actually quite straight forward.  You could likely extract out the pertinent piece containing a URL or Email and pass that directly to the `urlize` function.

The reason Django cannot mark only one portion of the string as safe, is that it marks the entire string as safe and returns a safe string object.  If you want only part of the string to be safe then it must be cut from the parent string and made safe on it's own (there isn't support for only part of a string to be sanitized, you either sanitize the entire string or none of it).

This is made VERY clear in the source for `SafeText`

```
class SafeText(six.text_type, SafeData):
    """
    A unicode (Python 2) / str (Python 3) subclass that has been specifically
    marked as "safe" for HTML output purposes.
    """
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        """
        Concatenating a safe unicode string with another safe byte string or
        safe unicode string is safe. Otherwise, the result is no longer safe.
        """
        t = super(SafeText, self).__add__(rhs)
        if isinstance(rhs, SafeData):
            return SafeText(t)
        return t

    def _proxy_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Wrap a call to a normal unicode method up so that we return safe
        results. The method that is being wrapped is passed in the 'method'
        argument.
        """
        method = kwargs.pop('method')
        data = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(data, bytes):
            return SafeBytes(data)
        else:
            return SafeText(data)

    encode = curry(_proxy_method, method=six.text_type.encode)
```